# How do i subtract two lists with non-unique elements in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two lists like:

```
list1 = ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

list_final = list2 - list1
list_final = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I don't think the approach of *set(lists)* and using *.difference* would help because its not a unique set.
Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated and im new to the language so any and all answers/tips are welcome!

Comment: So `list2` is always sorted?

Comment: And all `list1` elements always appear at least as often in `list2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the order is not important, you can make [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s from the lists and subtract them.

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

final = Counter(list2) - Counter(list1)

print(list(final.elements()))  # -> ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

It's being used as a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

There are some caveats to "order is not important", like the fact that dicts in Python 3.7+ will preserve insertion order, hence why the output here is ordered.

Answer (score 4):

`list.remove` should be enough here, even though not the most efficient way of doing it as `.remove` has a `O(n)` complexity.

```py
list1 = ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'k']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for e in list1:
    try:
        list2.remove(e)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{e} not in list')

list2
# ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: To be clear, this is O(n^2) at worst.

Comment: @wjandrea O(m*n). Two different lists with different lengths.

Comment: `O(n*m)` for the whole process but `O(n)` for the remove itself, right ?

Comment: @khelwood Yes, thanks, I just realized that myself. For anyone else reading, m=len(list1), n=len(list2).

Comment: @RobinFrcd yes, exactly